# How do I add an overlayfs to /etc/fstab?

Tags: 14.04, mount, fstab, overlayfs

On Ubuntu v14.04, I have a drive mounted at `/mnt/log-overlay` that I would like to mount over the top of `/var/log`.

The following mount command successfully creates that overlay, and works fine:

```
mount -t overlayfs -o lowerdir=/var/log,upperdir=/mnt/log-overlay overlayfs /var/log
```

What do I need to add to `/etc/fstab` to make sure this overlay mounts at boot?

```
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /    ext4   defaults,discard    0 0
/dev/xvde   /mnt/log-overlay    auto    defaults,nobootwait,comment=cloudconfig 0   2
[what-goes-here?]
```

Answer (score 8):

From the figure-it-out-as-you-post-the-question department.

The following `/etc/fstab` entry successfully mounts `/mnt/log-overlay` on top of `/var/log` at boot:

```
overlayfs   /var/log    overlayfs   defaults,lowerdir=/var/log,upperdir=/mnt/log-overlay,comment=cloudconfig    0   2
```

Previous `fstab` entries:

```
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /    ext4   defaults,discard    0 0
/dev/xvde   /mnt/log-overlay    auto    defaults,nobootwait,comment=cloudconfig 0   2
```

Comment: FYI if your overlay mount references other non-root disks, there is no deterministic guarantee those will be available when the overlay mount is processed (mounts are forked in parallel). This will cause a mount failure during reboots - and enter into maintenance mode. To avoid this add the `noauto` to the (4th) options field. And add a post-boot script to mount the overlay when all local disks are up.

Comment: Good point @colminator. That "post-boot script" could also be the mount command directly...